# Webpack mini-css-extract-plugin @font-face url resolution issue

Tags: webpack, path, font-face, webpack-file-loader, mini-css-extract-plugin

I am facing difficulty understanding the nature of URLs/paths and how they are resolved while using the `mini-css-extract-plugin`, `file-loader` and configuring their options such as the `context` and `filename` properties.

I am developing a custom theme for WordPress, with the custom theme's folder being where I have initialized the npm project/package.json file and webpack.config.js file. I am using the browser-sync plugin to proxy the local WordPress server to the browser-sync server.

The file-loader is emitting the files into the dist>assets>fonts folder. But the URL being generated in the compiled CSS file is not being resolved correctly.

**output CSS, browser console error**

```
GET http://localhost:4444/wp-content/themes/test/dist/css/assets/fonts/my-font.ttf net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

GET http://localhost:4444/wp-content/themes/test/dist/css/assets/fonts/my-font.woff 404 (Not Found)
```

In the error above the url shows `dist/css/assets/fonts/my-font.woff`, which is not what I expected. It was expected to be `dist/assets/fonts/my-font.woff` since that is where file-loader emits the files in the dist folder. (as defined in the file-loader context option)

I don't understand why it is adding the `css` directory to the fonts url. The only mention of the `dist/css` path is in the filename property of the MiniCSSExtractPlugin options. Since that is where i would like the css file to be output.

This can be confirmed by removing the `css` path prefix on the filename property. The url then resolves correctly relative to the dist path, but then the compiled css file is placed in the root of the dist folder instead of its own `dist/css` sub-directory.

**mini css extract plugin options**

```
new MiniCSSExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'css/[name].css',
        }),
```

**font-face rule in scss file**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'my-font';
  src: url("../assets/fonts/my-font.eot");
  src: url("../assets/fonts/my-font.eot") format("embedded-opentype"),
  url("../assets/fonts/my-font.ttf") format("truetype"),
  url("../assets/fonts/my-font.woff") format("woff"),
  url("../assets/fonts/my-font.svg") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: block;
}
```

**webpack config entry and output**

```
 entry: {
        'frontend': './src/js/frontend.js',
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: "js/[name].js"
    },
```

**module.rules**

```
module: {
        rules: [
            {...},
            {
                test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCSSExtractPlugin.loader
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader"
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader"
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|svg|ttf)([\?]?.*)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                            name: '[path][name].[ext]'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
```

**plugins**

```
plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new BrowserSyncWebpackPlugin({...}),
        new MiniCSSExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'css/[name].css',
        }),
    ]
```

I am a beginner at webpack and I am facing several difficulties trying to get font-face URLs to resolve correctly. I have a feeling that I don't understand the purpose of relative/absolute paths, context and publicpath in the webpack config. How is the URL in the compiled CSS is being determined?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Interestingly i am also facing this question while developing package and so i was not installing webpack, webpack-cli and devserver in my node_modules but rather using global webpack. I can confirm if we use webpack from node_modules then path resolves correctly and we don't have to set publicPath option in minicssextract plugin.

Answer (score 3):

I came across your question when I was having the same issue. I eventually managed to resolve it by using the `publicPath` option for the MiniCssExtractPlugin.

My directory structure looks like this, where `assets` contains the working files and `build` contains the compiled files. The webroot of my project is `/src`.

```
/src
  /assets
    /css
    /webfonts
  /build
    /css
    /webfonts
```

Therefore, by setting an absolute path for `publicPath`, it meant the font files in my CSS were referenced by the absolute file path, rather than a relative file path.

```
{
  loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
  options: {
    publicPath: '/build/',
  },
},
```

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
url("../assets/fonts/my-font.ttf") format("truetype"),
```

to

```
url("../assets/fonts/my-font.ttf") format("ttf"),
```